# Unix Regular Expression - how to represent a group of numbers

Tags: regex, unix

I have to represent the file name ARCLOSE.TXT.20140822123645 using Regular expression.
File name is broken into two parts : ARCLOSE.TXT and 20140822123645.I can represent ARCLOSE.TXT with *. But I want to know how to represent the group of numbers.
I have seen expressions like *.[0-9][0-9] , but there could be any amount of numbers in the file name ,so [0-9] will not work. Is there any other way to represent the file name I have provided?

Comment: `\+`? Shouldn't it just be `[0-9]+` or `\d+`?

Comment: @Allendar: with tools like grep and sed in basic mode `+` is seen as a literal character and must be escaped if you want write a quantifier. About `\d`, it doesn't exist at all. Note too that `\d` in other tools/languages can have different meanings, since it can include non-ascii digits or not.

Comment: the major issue is "do you expect to use shell globing reg-ex, or a language reg-ex"?. Please edit your question to include that important piece of information ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah yes, I'm sorry I was a bit hasty and overlooked that. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Testing on regex101.com, if you want to capture this value, there are different syntaxes based on which language you are using.

[image]